# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onfocus' of null

Tags: javascript

I am trying to learn JavaScript and I'm building this basic tutorial. In trying to demonstrate  onfocus and onblur, I get this error message in my JavaScript console: Uncaught TypeError: cannot set property 'onfocus' of null.

Here is my code. I am new to learning JavaScript and could really use some help.

```
//alert("Hello, world!"); 
// this is a JavaScript alert button 
//
var year = 2014;
var userEmail = "";
var todaysDate = "";
/*var donation = 20;

if (donation < 20) {
    alert("For a $20 you get a cookie. Change your donation?");
}
else {
    alert("Thank you!");
} */

var mainfile = document.getElementById("mainTitle");
console.log("This is an element of type: ", mainTitle.nodeType);
console.log("The inner HTML is ", mainTitle.innerHTML);
console.log("Child nodes: ", mainTitle.childNodes.length);

var myLinks = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
console.log("Links: ", myLinks.length);

var myListElements = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
console.log("List elements: ", myListElements.length);

var myFirstList = document.getElementById("2 paragraphs");
/* you can also use: var limitedList = myFirstList.getElementsByTagName("li");
to dig deeper into the DOM */
var myElement = document.createElement("li");
var myNewElement = document.createElement("li");
//myNewElement.appendChild(myNewElement); 

var myText = document.createTextNode("New list item");
myNewElement.appendChild(myText); 

// creating elements
var newListItem = document.createElement("li");
var newPara = document.createElement("p");

// To add content, either use inner HTML
// or create child nodes manually like so:
// newPara.innerHTML = "blah blah blah...";
var paraText = document.createTextNode("And now for a beginner level intro to JavaScript! YAY!");
newPara.appendChild(paraText);

//And we still need to attach them to the document
document.getElementById("basic").appendChild(newPara);

var myNewElement = document.createElement("li");
var secondItem = myElement.getElementsByTagName("li")[1];
myElement.insertBefore(myNewElement, secondItem);

// An example of using an anonymous function: onclick.
//When you click anywhere on the page, an alert appears.
//document.onclick = function() {
//  alert("You clicked somewhere in the document");
//}

// And example of restricting the click alert to 
// an element on the page.
var myImage = document.getElementById("mainImage");
myImage.onclick = function() {
    alert("You clicked on the picture!");
}

function prepareEventHandlers() {
    var myImage = document.getElementById("mainImage");
    myImage.onclick = function() {
      alert("You clicked on the picture!");
    }
    //onfocus and onblur event handler illustration
    var emailField = document.getElementById("email");
    emailField.onfocus = function() {
    if (emailField.value == "your email") {
        emailField.value = "";
    }
};

    emailField.onblur = function() {
    if (emailField.value == "") {
        emailField.value = "your email";
    }
};

}


window.onload = function() {
    // preps everything and ensures 
    // other js functions don't get
    // called before document has
    // completely loaded.
    prepareEventHandlers(); // This is a named function call nested inside an anonymous function.
}



//Sometimes we want js to run later or call a
// function in 60 seconds or every 5 sec, etc.
// Two main methods for timers: setTimeout and setInterval
// these timer functions are in milliseconds

var myImage = document.getElementById("mainImage");
var imageArray = ["images/Blue-roses.jpg", "images/Purple-Rose.jpg", "images/White-Rose.jpg", "images/orange-rose.jpg", "images/pink-roses.jpg", "images/red-roses.jpg", "images/yellow-roses.jpg", "images/murdock.jpg", "images/dorothy-red-ruby-slippers.jpg"];
var imageIndex = 0;

function changeImage(){
    myImage.setAttribute("src",imageArray[imageIndex]);
    imageIndex++;
    if (imageIndex >= imageArray.length) {
        imageIndex = 0;
    }
}
setInterval(changeImage, 5000);

//Sometimes we may want some random alert
// to pop up x-number of seconds later.
//So we use the setTimeout, like so:
/*function simpleMessage() {
    alert("Get ready to learn!");
}
setTimeout(simpleMessage, 5000); */

/*var_dump($_POST);
  if var_dump($_POST) = "";
  return var($_GET); 
  error_log($_POST); */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's giving you that error, then it means that `document.getElementById("email")` evaluates to `null`, which means that no element exists with the id `email`.

That's all I can tell you without seeing the HTML that this JS is connected to.

Comment: Thank you, Astro. I went back to double-check my HTML for the id of that element and for some weird reason I set the id="name" instead of id="email", so I fixed it now and that solved the problem and your answer makes perfect sense. Thank you.